# Clear <option value> on form submit

Tags: javascript, html

As part of a html form, i have a select box.

```
<select id="test" name="test">
<option value="text1">Text1</option>
<option value="text2">Text2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="my_text_box" name="my_text_box" class="hidden" />
```

Using javascript, how can I remove the value "text2" from the results the form emails to me?

EDIT:

I need to keep Text2. When the user selects this, the select box changes to a text input, using the script below. I need to remove the value "text2" from the resulting text input.

```
 window.onload = function(){
 var dropDown = document.getElementById("test");
 dropDown.onchange = function() {
 var dropDownValue = this.value;
 if (dropDownValue == "text2") {
    dropDown.style.display = 'none';
    var textBox = document.getElementById("my_text_box");
    textBox.style.display = 'inline';
    textBox.value = 'Please enter something..';
  } else {
    dropDown.style.display = 'inline';
    textBox.style.display = 'none';
   };

   }
```

Comment: did you try anything??

Comment: What do you mean by remove the value "text2". Why don't you get rid of the whole `<select>` then?

Comment: if the form is sent and the select is not multiple,only the selected value will be sent. And what does it have anything to do with emailing?

Comment: When the user selects "Text2" the select box changes to a text input. I can't get rid of the value "text2". Will post the complete script.

Comment: Could you share the code that you have now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 document.getElementById('test').options[1].value = 'emailId';
```